# HTML to PDF Javascript (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, printing

I am using Angular 8 and have pretty styled HTML that I want to implement a "print to PDF" functionality. I looked into just "window.print()" but it doesn't sound like I can get rid of the default header/footer on the browsers programmatically. I wanted to know if anyone knew a good way through Angular/JS to generate a PDF with this styled HTML?

Comment: You can do this with libraries like jsPDF, but depending on your requirements, this process can be a lot of extra work

Comment: Yeah I have been looking into jsPDF. It's dynamic HTML that was set in a WYSIWYG, so anything to preserve the styling there. Plus some divs require a border around them. That is why I would prefer being able to convert the HTML directly into the PDF, if possible

Answer (score 0):

`window.print()` won't print to PDF by itself, it will simply invoke the print dialog, from which you can pick a destination printer, which could include a physical printer or a PDF printer software you may have installed.

If you are happy with that solution, and your only concern is that headers and footers are being printed, you should make use of CSS media queries. CSS media queries allow you to specify different styles for on-screen display vs. print on paper (and other cases).

In your stylesheet, assuming your header and footer elements are called just like that, you can do:

```css
@media print {
  header, footer { display: none; }
}
```

You can also make them styled differently (e.g. slimmer) instead of hiding completely.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Sorry, I mean the header and footer that the print generates. Like the URL, date, etc.

Comment: That you can disable in the print dialog. Depending on what OS you are using, look for a checkbox or inputs called something like "Print header and footer".

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for an option that did not rely on the user unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

With angular 2

- pdfmake :: [pdfmake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/)
- pdfkit :: [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit)

For Angularjs

You can see [this](https://itnext.io/angularjs-exporting-to-pdf-using-pdfmake-js-library-49f3afec97ef) tutorial in MEDIUM (pdfmake)